# stop refreshing _navigation partial view in mvc layout or load the _navigation only 1 time

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a standard MVC layout with nav(slide off navigation).

Header & footer are partial views & referred to in views. Every time I click on nav link the total page refreshes and missing the active navbar position(placement). How can I best solve this issue? Any suggestions are welcome. 
My _layout.cshtml is..

```
    <!--Wrapper-->     
        <div id="wrapper">

        <!--Navigation--> 

@Html.Partial("_Navigation")    

<!--Page wraper-->    
            <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

                @Html.Partial("_TopNavbar")

                <!-- Main view-->    
                @RenderBody()    

                <!-- Footer -->
                @Html.Partial("_Footer")            
</div>
            <!-- End page wrapper-->

        </div>

and i tried the load method like follows..
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.stop_refresh").click(function (e) 
    {
     e.preventDefault(); var url = $(this).attr("href"); $('#page-wrapper').load(url); 
        });
```

Comment: Your nav links are probably `<a href="..page2">` - if you don't want to load the whole page, then you need to change these to ajax requests to load the content - this doesn't sound like what you want to do at this stage.  Alternatively, your page needs to indicate to the navigation component which page it is and update the nav view accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You could have the nav link as a ajax call. As a response server would send you generated HTML - with which you would then (with jquery / javascript) replace the old HTML part of page which you are trying to reload.
For better effect add some kind of loader to the part of page that is being refreshed/ reloaded (it should start as first event on click and end when a response from ajax call is received).
But it is just too much work for most pages and since some elements can change, the amount of code/ time that you would spend on it just isnt a viable option for the most part.

Comment: Please explore what i did in that ajax call() ? why I can't get load the path (../controler/index.cshtm) like.

Comment: @Shankar, the ajax call would have a path to your controller (/controller/index) which would have a fuction like public IActionResult Index() {return View();}.. which would open your Controller/Index.chstml razor page. But for what OP was asking, you woulc have a function like this (using jquery): $("#linkId").on('click', function(){
$.ajax({
type: 'get',
url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")' 
success: funciton(data){
 })
})

Answer (score 0):

@Shankar, the ajax call would have a path to your controller (/controller/index) which would have a fuction like public IActionResult Index() {return View();}.. which would open your Controller/Index.cshtml razor page. But for what OP was asking, you woulc have a function like this (using jquery):

```
$("#linkId").on('click', function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: '@Url.Action("myAction", "myController")' 
    success: function(data){
      $("#myPageHolder").html(data);
    }
 })
})
```

The Url Action could point to a partial view which would be returned as
'data' variable and be 'plugged in' to the page by replacing the html in a div with id myPageHolder.